# изменено по POS API - через приложение "Касса МойСклад"

Tags: мойсклад-api

Изменение заказа через по  POS API вызывает webhook UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

Да, т.к. изменяется документ. Неважно откуда инициируется изменение, UI или API, важен сам факт.

Comment: Как это можно проверить? Есть подозрение, что все-таки не работает...

Comment: 1.Проверьте работу вебхука вот по этой инструкции https://moysklad.github.io/workbook/api/remap/1.1/ru/webhooks.html
2.Если есть сомнения, то приложите запрос к POS API для изменения документа в формате CURL